# Protractor - unable to get h2 value

Tags: protractor

I'm unable to get value from h2 tag using protractor.
Html Code:

```
<h2 class="ng-binding">7</h2>
```

I need this 7 value. This is from website "http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/". I am adding 5+2.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xpath
Here I am getting the element with ID, moving one position back and then looking for the h2

```
var result = element(by.xpath('//*[@id=\'gobutton\']/../h2'))
result.getText().then(function(value){
  expect(value).toBe('7');
})
```

Or look directly to the h2:

```
element(by.xpath('//h2[@class='ng-binding']'))
```

In case you plan to always have 7 as a result then you can also look for the cssContainingText

```
var result = element.all(by.cssContainingText('.ng-binding', '7')).first();
```

in this case I am using .all and .first because this will return 2 elements so I am telling protractor to use always the first one

So your code should be something like this:

```
it('Should access the page and perform sum', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    element(by.model('first')).sendKeys(5);
    element(by.model('second')).sendKeys(2);
    element(by.id('gobutton')).click();

    var result = element(by.xpath('//*[@id=\'gobutton\']/../h2'))
    result.getText().then(function(value){
        console.log('result is '+value)
        expect(value).toBe('7');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre

Comment: No problem, if this solved your problem please accept this as answer so people wont keep answering something closed already. @MohitGarg

Answer (score 0):

As per the url given, After clicking `Go` it loads for some time. So add some wait and then try to `getText()` with the below locator.

`browser.sleep(5000);
element(by.css('form>h2.ng-binding')).getText().then((text: String) =>{
expect(text).toBe("7");
})`

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

First, you find the `element`, for example with a `by.css` call. Then you use `getText` method to retrieve the desired tag content. Finally, you assert it to be equal to the value you expect:

```
result = element(by.css('h2.ng-binding'))
expect(result.getText()).toEqual('7')
```